# End of File detection in ESPER

Tags: esper, epl, complex-event-processing

I am using ESPER to read events from a CSV file.
How can I make the query output something when reading a CSV file is finished.

For example i want to output every 30 min or at the end of the file

```
SELECT id FROM stream output every 30 min or [ EOF reached ]
```

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The "adapter.start()" finishes when the CSV file is done and the code can send a EOF event into the engine. You could declare a context that ends on that EOF event and there is a "output every 30 minutes and when terminated" option.